# WTK emulator bluetooth connection

Tags: java, bluetooth, java-me, emulation, java-wireless-toolkit

I'm developing a J2ME program with eclipse / WTK 2.5.2 and having problem with connecting two emulators using bluetooth. There is one server and one .client running on two different emulators.

The problem is client program cannot discover any bluetooth device. Here is the server and client codes:

```
public Server()
{
    try
    {
        LocalDevice local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);

        server = (StreamConnectionNotifier)   
            Connector.open("btspp://localhost:" 
                + UUID_STRING + ";name=" + SERVICE_NAME);

        Util.Log("EchoServer() Server connector open!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

after calling Connector.open, I get following warning in console, which i believe is related:

***Warning: Unregistered device: unspecified***

and client code that searches for devices:

```
public SearchForDevices(String uuid, String nm)
{
    UUIDStr = uuid;
    srchServiceName = nm;
    try
    {
        LocalDevice local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        agent = local.getDiscoveryAgent();

        deviceList = new Vector();

        agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, this); // non-blocking
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

system never calls deviceDiscovered, but calls inquiryCompleted() with INQUIRY_COMPLETED parameter, so I suppose client program runs fine.

Bluetooth is enabled at emulator settings..

Comment: You are running those 2 emulators on 2 different computers, right? can you find a third device that way (like a bluetooth-enabled mobile phone in the same room)?

Comment: no i use them in the same computer..

Comment: Bluetooth is typically the kind of network protocol I would NOT trust with loopback connections. What you're attempting is not close enough to a real-life use case, IMHO.

Comment: hey, thanks for your response.. but it is not a loopback, because I'm running 2 different emulators.. server code runs at 555000 and client runs at 555001. in theory they would act like two physical phones..

Comment: You're still only using your host Win7 computer bluetooth stack in loopback

Answer (score 3):

I tested almost same code from NetBeans IDE 6.8 with WTK 2.5.2_01 emulator and it works well. (I mean it discovered device)

```
public void startBTServer() {
    try
    {
        LocalDevice local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);

        StreamConnectionNotifier server = (StreamConnectionNotifier)
            Connector.open("btspp://localhost:F0E0D0C0B0A000908070605040302010"
                + ";name=" + ";test");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}

public void startBTClient() {
    String UUIDStr = "F0E0D0C0B0A000908070605040302010";
    try
    {
        LocalDevice local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        DiscoveryAgent agent = local.getDiscoveryAgent();

        agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, (DiscoveryListener) this);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}

}

public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
    System.out.println("device discovered:" + btDevice.toString());
}
```

This code print out the below log:

From server:

```
Running in the identified_third_party security domain
Device Bluetooth Address: 0000000DECAF
```

From client:

```
Device Bluetooth Address: 0123456789AF
device discovered:RemoteDevice[address=0000000DECAF, name=null, encrypted=false, authenticated=false]
```

Comment: hey, 
may be it is related with my OS, I'm using win7. do you know how bluetooth emulation is done in wtk emulator ?